# Applications of the change of variable formula for multiple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

> Calculate $\iint_R \frac{1}{x+y}dydx$ where $R$ is the region bounded by $x=0,y=0,x+y=1,x+y=4$ by using the mapping $T(u,v)=(u-uv,uv)$.

I find this exercise super confusing. $R$ is a parallelogram, so we need to find a simpler region; since $T$ is not linear, we can't assume that it maps parallelograms into parallelograms. Besides, I don't get whether we need to find an $R^*$ such that $R^*=T(R)$ or an $R^*$ such that $T(R^*)=R$.

If the former, then by setting $x=u-uv,y=uv$, we get

$$u-uv=0 \\ uv=0 \\ u = 1 \\ u = 4$$

But I don't know how to interpret this. The first equation has the solution set $\{(u,v) : u=0 \text{ or } v=1\}$ and the second equation has both axes as a solution set. There is no single region bounded by this equations.

I tried finding parametric curves $c_1,\dots,c_2$ for $R$'s borders and then finding the composition $T \circ c_i$ but the results were ghastly (parabolas).

I'd really like to learn how to be methodical with these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the region $R$ as covered by the segments $I(s)$, $1\le s\le 4$, which are connecting the points $(s,0)$ and $(0,s)$ placed on the axes. For a point $(x,y)$ on $I(s)$ we have of course the sum $s=x+y$. Now we also want to parametrize the segments. A natural choice is $x = su$, $y=s(1-u)$, where $u$ runs in $[0,1]$. We are thus in the situation to consider the relations
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= su\ ,\\
y &= s(1-u)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
s &= x+y\ ,
\\
u &= x/(x+y)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which connect $(x,y)\in R$ with $(s,u)\in[1,4]\times[0,1]$.

We have formally:
$$
\begin{aligned}
dx\wedge dy 
&= d(su)\wedge d(s(1-u))
\\
&=(s\; du+u\; ds)\wedge(-s\; du+(1-u)\; ds)
\\
&=(s(1-u)-u(-s))\; du\wedge ds
\\
&=s\; du\wedge ds
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the integral becomes
$$
\iint_R\frac 1{x+y}\; dx\ dy
=
\iint_{[0,1]\times[1,4]}\frac 1s\; s\; du\; ds
=
\iint_{[0,1]\times[1,4]} du\; ds
=
\operatorname{Area}([0,1]\times[1,4])
=3\ .
$$